# Symfony/Sonata template path file not found and how directory structures are arranged

Tags: php, symfony, templates, twig, sonata-admin

I am using Symfony v3.3.13 and Sonata Admin Bundle 3.27.0 with TWIG v2.4.4

I have a little problem understanding how twig template paths work. I have recently needed to load a new template for a list view field in `SonataAdminBundle`.

I had to define the path as follows:

```
->add('coords', null, ['template' => 'SonataAdmin/CRUD/geography_point_list.html.twig']);
```

The geography_point_list.html.twig file was in `app/Resources/views/SonatAdmin/Crud`

I also managed to get this work with the path `AppBundle::SonataAdmin/CRUD/geography_point_list.html.twig`. However then the file should be in `src/AppBundle/Resources/views/SonatAdmin/Crud`

However I see in all examples that the template file path is divided by colon `:` instead of slash `/` yet, I cant get something like `AppBundle:SonataAdmin:CRUD:geography_point_list.html.twig` to work. I tried several variations and I always get `Unable to find template`. None of the following worked (I have the in both `app/Resources/views/SonataAdmin/CRUD` and `src/AppBundle/Resources/views/SonataAdmin/Crud`:

```
->add('coords', null, ['template' => 'App:SonataAdmin:CRUD:geography_point_list.html.twig']);

->add('coords', null, ['template' => 'AppBundle:SonataAdmin:CRUD:geography_point_list.html.twig']);

->add('coords', null, ['template' => 'AppBundle:app:Resources:views:SonataAdmin:CRUD:geography_point_list.html.twig']);

->add('coords', null, ['template' => 'App::SonataAdmin:CRUD:geography_point_list.html.twig']);

->add('coords', null, ['template' => 'AppBundle::SonataAdmin:CRUD:geography_point_list.html.twig']);
```

OK. So I have 2 questions:

1- Why it doesn't work? What am I doing wrong? or what may be missing? Because I can see that paths like `SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list.html.twig` is defined in `SonataAdminBundle` and they seem to be working?

2- In [template naming and locations documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating.html#template-naming-and-locations) it says the correct place to put the templates is `app/Resources/views`

a) Is storing templates in `AppBundle` deprecated?
  b) Why it doesnt make sense to store the templates in `AppBundle` directory instead? What I don't understand is why `app` directory has `config` and `Resources` separate from `AppBundle`?

Comment: Could you provide us the version of the Symfony and SonataAdminBundle that you have?

Comment: Symfony v3.3.13 and Sonata Admin Bundle 3.27.0 with TWIG v2.4.4

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26400579/symfony-2-path-to-template?rq=1) should help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I think it doesn't work because you should try `BundleName:DirectoryInViewsFolder:Subfolder/template.html.twig`. So in your case it is `AppBundle:SonataAdmin:CRUD/geography_point_list.html.twig`.
2. Right, you can put them there.

   a) In symfony 3 i don't think so.

   b) I guess what in `app/Resources` and `app/config` there are global resources and configs for your application. And resources and configs for your bundle you put in `src/BundleName/Resources` and `src/BundleName/config` folders.

BTW you can also use your [custom templates paths](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/namespaced_paths.html#registering-your-own-namespaces):

config.yml

```
twig:
    paths:
        '%kernel.project_dir%/src/YourBundle/templates': templates
```

YourAdmin.php

```
->add('coords', null, ['template' => '@templates/geography_point_list.html.twig']);
```

**UPDATE**

This answer is not fully correct. It was helpful for Evren Yurtesen but you should see the right answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41086434/8901178).

Comment: I think the documentation is very unclear about how this works. `BundleName:DirectoryInViewsFolder:Path/To/Template/Relative/To/Directory/In/Views` would have been a simple example to put to symfony/sonata documentation... :( Thanks for the great explanation!

Comment: Oh, nice example. I'll change it in my answer. Glad to help you.

Comment: Yes, the problem was that all examples using colon `:` had only colons in them. So I thought one uses colon `:` instead of `/`. It was not clear to where colons start and where they end. So I coded the whole path with colons which was a mistake. Perhaps it is better to end the example path with a filename (makes it shorter) `BundleName:DirectoryInViewsFolder:Path/To/Template.html.twig` Anyway, thanks for the effort. By the way, also `BundleName::DirectoryInViewsFolder/Path/To/Template.html.twig` also works...